# Downloading and uploading files without ftp and sftp

Tags: java, active-directory, jcifs, j-integra

I want to get download and upload from a remote windows machine(workgroup,or domain) to my local unix machine.I dont want to use Sftp or FTP server.I also consider the Jcifs(smb) librariy but it only allowing  access to shared directories.I want to access any directory with sufficent user permission.How can i do this I think active directory has a capability.

Comment: Isn't the definition of a shared directory one with sufficient user permissions to share?

Comment: But it also need marked as shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just open up a samba share on your unix machine and connect to the share from your windows machine.

Comment: I want to download and upload files from/to a windows machine to my local unix machine and i want to do it with only username and password ,no need to any configure at remote windows machine.

Comment: @ayengin no configuration is necessary on the windows machine. Setting up a samba share is (as far as I know) fairly simple to do. Then you open the share on your windows machine (i.e. browse to it like a folder) and dump your files.